# Trajectory Prediction in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to predict where an object (ball) will move using the following formula

Calculations for t = 1 second

```
y = VelocityY * t + 0.5*Gravity*t2
x = VelocityX * t
```

code below:

```
    +(CGVector) getTrajectoryPointWithInitialPosition:(CGVector) initialPosition andInitialVelocity:(CGVector) initialVelocity andSteps: (CGFloat)n andSceneLayer: (SKScene*) sceneLayer
    {
    // Put data into correct units
    CGFloat t = 1.0 / 60.0;

    // m/s
    CGVector stepVelocity = CGVectorMake(t * initialVelocity.dx, t * initialVelocity.dy);


    // m/s^2
    CGVector stepGravity = CGVectorMake(t * t * sceneLayer.physicsWorld.gravity.dx, t * t * sceneLayer.physicsWorld.gravity.dy);

    initialPosition = CGVectorMake(initialPosition.dx + n * stepVelocity.dx,
                                   initialPosition.dy + n * stepVelocity.dy + 0.5 * (n*n+n) * stepGravity.dy);

    return CGVectorMake(initialPosition.dx + n * stepVelocity.dx,
                        initialPosition.dy + n * stepVelocity.dy + 0.5 * (n*n) * stepGravity.dy);
}
```

I then launch the ball (stationary/non-dynamic) using the following

```
CGVector aVelocity = CGVectorMake(initialVelocity.dx*17.5, initialVelocity.dy*17.5);
[ball.physicsBody setVelocity:aVelocity];
```

What I can't figure out is:

initialVelocity for the ball and the trajectory prediction is the same. If it's the same, why does multiplying initialVelocity for the ball by 17.5 gets the ball movement and the predicted trajectory obtained from above to match up. It looks like it's following the predicted path but I don't understand why multiplying the balls velocity by 17.5 makes the ball

![Before multiplying by 17.5] https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE14F.png - Before multiplying by 17.5
![After multiplying velocity by 17.5] https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYwE9.png - After multiplying by 17.5

Comment: sprite kit physics is not deterministic, you can not predict its simulation accurately 100%, things will deviate from your prediction over time

Comment: Not being able to predict things 100% in sprite kit is ok but I can't tell what's so special about the number 17.5. Results are completely different using the same velocity for both prediction and launching the ball. Multiplyin velocity for the ball ONLY, by 17.5, has the ball follow the predicted path.

Comment: Create a copy of the ball, set alpha to 0 (to make it invisible). Make the invisible ball follow the trajectory before the actual ball does, and in the contact method find the position of the invisible ball and delete it. This position is where the ball will land (and you can now launch the real one), only with the assumption that it does not 'bounce'. If it should collide with things, i'm afraid predicting the trajectory will be tougher.